# GWT MVP framework - Modules architecture

Tags: gwt, module, mvp

I'm a beginner at GWT MVP framework and my question is: I have  only one entry point module (acemproject) which inherits two other modules that I’ ve created recently. When I compile my project only the main module is deployed and the two other do not appear in the deploy dir. They should appear there too, right? One other doubt I have it is related to my html page. I added those lines:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="adminModule/adminModule.nocache.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="edupedagModule/edupedagModule.nocache.js"></script>
```

Is it right?
Any help, I’ll appreciate very much. If you know any application that I can be a good example, it would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Only modules with the entry point appear in the deploy directory - this is correct. And you should not include the scripts in the host page as you tried.